# Как сделать плеер на полный экран?

Tags: java, android

Я прописал в манифесте `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` чтобы был на полный экран, и это скрывает TitleBar, но не бар где Домой, Назад, итд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам манифест:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Перепробовал все FullScreen стили, не помогает, подскажите пожалуйте, как можно скрыть все как на ютьюбе.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разных версий Android это делаеться по разному.
Вот пример метода который нужно вызвать чтобы скрыть кнопки с учетом что програма будет выполняться на разных версиях ОС.

```
public void MakeItFullscreen() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {          
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Сработало. Один вопрос: в каждом Activity это нужно вызывать?

Comment: @TITAN  да, можно сделать этот метод статическим и вызывать из главоного актививти в метооде OnCreate.
Или может быть можно что то в манифест прописать типа: 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`